# EF CodeFirst Migration drop fields from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I use EF 6 and Code First to create my database

```
  public partial class PcContext : DbContext, IPcContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Order { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Statistic> Statistic { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new EntitiesContextInitializer());                        
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().
                HasMany(m => m.Statistics).
                WithOptional(o => o.User).
                WillCascadeOnDelete();

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

    }

    public class EntitiesContextInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<PcContext>
    {

        protected override void Seed(PcContext context)
        {

            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_Email ON \"User\" (Email)");
            //skip code 

            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
```

I have modified one model and remove property from it but the table column still left in database and I have started to get exception "`The model backing the 'PcContext' context has changed since the database was created.`" .

So I have created migration class using console and command `Enable-Migrations` and I do not get exception anymore but the column in database still exists and was not dropped by migration. Why? How to drop old column from table which do not map property in model anymore?

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Context.PcContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(PC.Data.Context.PcContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: How are you initializing the database? Can you post the code where you set the initializer?

Comment: what the command did you use for to update database?